# Pip install warning: missingno METADATA is missing

Tags: python, pip, missingno

Whenever I try to install any new package using pip, I get the following error:

> WARNING: Error parsing requirements for missingno: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/missingno-0.4.2.dist-info/METADATA

Nevertheless, when I try to reinstall this library (through `pip install missingno`), it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: missingno in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.4.2)

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/missingno-0.4.2.dist-info/METADATA'

Any hint at how to solve this? Will this affect future libraries installations?

Note: My pip version is pip 22.1.2, and my Python version is 3.8.5

Comment: can u try installing using the conda itself  conda install missingno